# Get publickKeyToken from pfx

Tags: python, .net, pfx

I'm having a hard time trying to calculate the publicKeyToken corresponding to a pfx file.

I'm building an publishing a ClickOnce application using VisualStudio. I have a code signing certificate `code_sign.pfx` that I'm using. In the resulting manifest, there are several fields identifying the certificate and key used for signing, the ones I'm interested in are `publicKeyToken` and `issuerKeyHash`.

According to Microsoft, `issuerKeyHash` should be "the SHA-1 hash of the public key of the certificate issuer" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/publisheridentity-element-clickonce-deployment?view=vs-2022). I'm able to recalculate this field:

- On windows by opening the certificate store, copying the "Public Key" field and calculating the SHA1 hash.
- On linux by loading the pfx using `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization pcks12`, retrieving the public_bytes from the public_key, dropping the first 22 bytes (??? no clue why) and calculating the SHA1 hash.

Again according to Microsoft, the `publicKeyToken` is "the last 8 bytes of the SHA-1 hash value of the public key under which the deployment manifest is signed" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/assemblyidentity-element-clickonce-deployment?view=vs-2022). However, I cannot find a way to calculate this from the pfx without using tools such as `sc.exe`. There is only 1 public key in the pfx certificate, and it is used to calculate the `issuerKeyHash`.

Is there a way to calculate the `publicKeyToken` from a pfx certificate ?